# writeToFile fails when writing to desktop

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, writetofile

I have this code snippet below. The purpose is to write the contents of an array to a plist file. When I run this I don´t get any errors and everything seems to be fine. The problem is that the file doesn´t appear on the desktop. I used writeToFile before in other projects without any problems. What is wrong with it? Greetings from Switzerland, Ronald Hofmann.

```
- (IBAction) doActionPlist: (NSButton *)  sender
{
NSString    *fileExt = @".plist";
NSArray *myResultArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"Product Number Unlimited Desktop:",
@"4DDP120-UUS001-ANLKR-17C6B",
@"4DDP130-UUS001-ANQEI-1BC12",
@"4USE120-UUS001-80BY1-1EAB0",
@"4USE130-UUS001-6NTUE-11D64",
@"qA0iHnw4EIgOALgAAAQCmUtj",
@"qA0iHnw6EIgAALgAAPUBhByg",
@"4DDP11U00USN001",
@"4DDP13U12USN001",
@"4UCL00U00USN001",
@"4UCL00U00USN010",
@"4UCL11U00USN001",
@"4UCL11U00USN010",
@"4UCL12U11USN001",
@"4UCL12U11USN010",
@"4UCL13U12USN001",
@"4UCL13U12USN010",
@"4USE12U11USN002",
@"4USE13U12USN002",
@"4UWE13U12USN999",
nil];

NSString *thePath  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/ronny/Desktop/Testfile%@",fileExt]     ;
[myResultArray writeToFile:thePath atomically:YES]           ;
```

}

Comment: Off the top of my head your code looks reasonable.

Have you double-checked to make sure that you're running the executable as your "ronny" user?

Does the writeToFile call return YES or NO (i.e., does it realize it's failing)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it can be difficult to debug this call because it only returns YES or NO with no further information about *why* it succeeded or failed.  The fact that it's not throwing any exceptions doesn't necessarily mean that nothing is going wrong; it just means that NSArray can't be bothered to tell you about it.

If you're really at wit's end, you might try converting your NSArray to NSData using NSPropertyListSerialization and then using [writeToFile:options:error](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) instead.  If you do this, post the error message and someone should be able to offer better debugging advice.

Comment: I did further investigation on this issue because I´m using the same thing in other projects and it works fine there. Now I found that I turned sandboxing on in this project and that prevents the file from being written. Turning sandboxing off it works. Is there no way to write to the desktop? What I don´t understand it doesn´t make my .plist file extension. Instead it writes Testfile(null)